# htaccess remove file extension and allow folder of same name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a link on my site

> x.icebreaker.com/products

and a file in directory

> x.icebreaker.com/products/bow

I have the following `.htaccess` file to allow removal of file extension in browser but I can't get the page to show up while there is a folder of the same name (it defaults to opening the folder

> x.icebreaker.com/products/

How do I fix this??

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php
```

if it was unclear the question is not how to get the page to load `x.icebreaker.com/products` it's how to get it **NOT** to load `x.icebreaker.com/products/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable `MultiViews` option also:

```
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Also replace your `.php` adding rule with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: The issue I am having is that when I try to load `x.icebreaker.com/products` it tries to load `x.icebreaker.com/products/index` and when the folder `products` does not exist the file `products.php` in the root directory does load (just not while the foder exists)

Comment: Test it after clearing your browser cache and test with a trailing slash i.e. `x.icebreaker.com/products/`

Comment: I cleared the cache and then tried with and without the trailing slash and i ended up with a trailing slash anyways and a 403 error

Comment: Change `Options` line to `Options All -MultiViews` and use `x.icebreaker.com/products/`

Comment: All I needed was that last little bit and it works beautifully